# calling two ajax call depending on each other but without async

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am creating dynamic menu from two rest api. Menu will be created by parent / child relation. That means id of parent ajax response will be pass to child ajax to fetch child records.

Issue is when I use `async false` for my child ajax call my website become slow and when I remove it than my menu does not render. Some help on that.

My code Parent call

```
var url;
url = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('GlobalTopNavMenu')/items?$select=Id,Title,Image,hasSubMenu,Link&$filter=Location eq 'GlobalNavigation'";
html = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav nav-topmrgn'>";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item) {
      if (item.hasSubMenu == "Yes") {
        html += "<li class='dropdown yamm-fw borderLeftY'><a href='#' title='' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>" + Res[item.Title] + "<b class='caret'></b></a>";
        html += getSubMenu(item.Id) + "</dl>";
        html += "<dl class=''><dd class='picHolder'><img alt='' src='/PublishingImages/" + item.Image + "'/></dd></dl></div></div></li></ul></li>";
      } else
        html += "<li class='yamm-fw borderLeftY'><a href='" + item.Link + "' title='' class='dropdown-toggle' role='link' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>" + Res[item.Title] + "</a></li>";
    })
    html += "</ul>";
    $("#navbar").empty();
    $("#navbar").append(html);
  }
});
```

Child call

```
function getSubMenu(id) {
  var url = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('GlobalSubNavMenu')/items?$select=Id,Title,Link,ParentMenu/Id,root&$filter=ParentMenu/Id eq " + id + "&$expand=ParentMenu/Id";
  var html = "";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    async: false,
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.d.results.length < 6)
        html += "<ul class='dropdown-menu width500 spaceLeft'>"; //
      else
        html += "<ul class='dropdown-menu width800 spaceLeft'>";
      html += "<li><div class='yamm-content'><div class='row'><dl class='col-sm-3 mega-menu colborderRight'>";
      $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item) {
        if (i !== 0 && i % 6 == 0)
          html += "</dl><dl class='col-sm-3 mega-menu colborderRight'><dd class=''><a href=/" + (item.root ? "" : lang) + item.Link + ">" + Res[item.Title] + "</a></dd>";
        else
          html += "<dd class=''><a href=/" + (item.root ? "" : lang) + item.Link + ">" + Res[item.Title] + "</a></dd>";
      });
    }
  });
  return html;
}
```

If I remove async false from child function than menu will not render. So how can I do that.

Comment: maybe this? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Kindly can you help based on my ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `async: false`, `getSubMenu()` is asynchrounous, therefore,

- `getSubMenu()` must return a promise (good practice) or accept a callback (bad practice),
- code that depends on data obtained from `getSubMenu()` must be factored accordingly.

This is not the simplest introduction to working with asynchronously derived data, particularly so because `getSubMenu()` is called from within a loop.

You need to understand the following :

- `jQuery.ajax()` returns a promise, allowing you to chain `.then()`. In solving this, you will benefit enormously from the extra power of `.then()` over a "success:" callback.
- `Array#map()` maps an array to a new array of whatever you like. Here `Array#map()` is particularly useful in creating an array of promises returned by `getSubMenu()`.
- `jQuery.when()` aggregates multiple promises and returns a single promise.

Here's a skeletonized pattern that will solve your problem :

```
$.ajax({...})
.then(function(data) { // then() not success: ...
    var promises = data.d.results.map(function(item) {
        if (item.hasSubMenu == 'Yes') {
            return getSubMenu(item.Id).then(function(subMenu) {
                return '...'; // build and return an HTML string here, including the `subMenu` created by `getSubMenu()`.
            });
        } else {
            return '...'; // return hard-coded HTML. 
        }
    });
    // At this point, promises is an array comprising some unknown mix of jQuery promises and HTML strings.
    return jQuery.when.apply(null, promises).then(function(/* each argument is an HTML fragment, as generated above */) {
        var html = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, ''); // slightly awkward syntax for joining `arguments` into a single string.
        $("#navbar").html('...' + html + '...');
    });
});

function getSubMenu(id) {
    var url = "...";
    return $.ajax({...}}) // getSubMenu() must return a promise.
    .then(function(data) { // then() not success: ...
        var html = "..."; // initial HTML fragment
        var arr = data.d.results.map(function(item) {
            return '...'; // build and return HTML based on item. 
        });
        // At this point, `arr` is an array of HTML fragments, that can be concatenated with Array#join().
        return html + '...' +  arr.join('') + '...'; // by using .then(), the promise returned by getSubMenu() will deliver whatever is returned here.
    });
}
```

In full :

```
var url = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('GlobalTopNavMenu')/items?$select=Id,Title,Image,hasSubMenu,Link&$filter=Location eq 'GlobalNavigation'";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    }
}).then(function(data) {
    var promises = data.d.results.map(function(item) {
        if (item.hasSubMenu == 'Yes') {
            return getSubMenu(item.Id).then(function(subMenu) {
                return '<li class="dropdown yamm-fw borderLeftY"><a href="#" title="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' + Res[item.Title] + '<b class="caret"></b></a>' + subMenu + '<dl class=""><dd class="picHolder"><img alt="" src="/PublishingImages/' + item.Image + '"/></dd></dl></div></div></li></ul></li>';
            });
        } else {
            return '<li class="yamm-fw borderLeftY"><a href=#"' + item.Link + '" title="" class="dropdown-toggle" role="link" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">' + Res[item.Title] + '</a></li>';
        }
    });
    return $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
        $("#navbar").html('<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-topmrgn">' + Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, '') + '</ul>');
    });
});

function getSubMenu(id) {
    var url = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('GlobalSubNavMenu')/items?$select=Id,Title,Link,ParentMenu/Id,root&$filter=ParentMenu/Id eq " + id + "&$expand=ParentMenu/Id";
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
        }
    }).then(function(data) {
        var html = (data.d.results.length < 6) ? '<ul class="dropdown-menu width500 spaceLeft">' : '<ul class="dropdown-menu width800 spaceLeft">';
        html += '<li><div class="yamm-content"><div class="row">';
        var arr = data.d.results.map(function(item) {
            return '<dd class=""><a href=/' + (item.root ? '' : lang) + item.Link + '>' + Res[item.Title] + '</a></dd>';
        });
        return html + '<dl class="col-sm-3 mega-menu colborderRight">' +  arr.join('') + '</dl>';
    });
}
```

Comment: let me try and get back to you\

Comment: Your code did not give any error but it is undefined. I think we are not evaluating variables

Comment: Hi figure out the issue and it is working fluently. I love you. But I like you to edit your code when you map first argument is item and another is index so you have to change that in both function. Another remove async:false from getSubMenu

Comment: Yes, I forgot to swap the arguments. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your function a bit as below

```
var url;
url = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('GlobalTopNavMenu')/items?$select=Id,Title,Image,hasSubMenu,Link&$filter=Location eq 'GlobalNavigation'";
html = "<ul class='nav navbar-nav nav-topmrgn'>";
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var totalMenus = data.d.results.length;
    $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item) {
        getSubMenu(item, function (submenuMarkup) {
            html += submenuMarkup;
            if (totalMenus === (i+1)) {
                html += "</ul>";
                $("#navbar").empty();
                $("#navbar").append(html);
            }
        });
    });
  }
});
```

getSubMenu will have a callback function as param, and returns the generated submenumarkup.

```
function getSubMenu(mainItem, cb) {
  var subMenuMarkup = "";
  var innerSubMenuMarkup = "";

  if (!(mainItem.hasSubMenu == "Yes")) {
    subMenuMarkup = "<li class='yamm-fw borderLeftY'><a href='" + mainItem.Link + "' title='' class='dropdown-toggle' role='link' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>" + Res[mainItem.Title] + "</a></li>";
    cb(subMenuMarkup);
    return;
  }


  var url = "/_api/lists/getbytitle('GlobalSubNavMenu')/items?$select=Id,Title,Link,ParentMenu/Id,root&$filter=ParentMenu/Id eq " + mainItem.Id + "&$expand=ParentMenu/Id";

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.d.results.length < 6)
        innerSubMenuMarkup += "<ul class='dropdown-menu width500 spaceLeft'>"; //
      else
        innerSubMenuMarkup += "<ul class='dropdown-menu width800 spaceLeft'>";

      innerSubMenuMarkup += "<li><div class='yamm-content'><div class='row'><dl class='col-sm-3 mega-menu colborderRight'>";

      $.each(data.d.results, function(i, item) {
        if (i !== 0 && i % 6 == 0)
          innerSubMenuMarkup += "</dl><dl class='col-sm-3 mega-menu colborderRight'><dd class=''><a href=/" + (item.root ? "" : lang) + item.Link + ">" + Res[item.Title] + "</a></dd>";
        else
          innerSubMenuMarkup += "<dd class=''><a href=/" + (item.root ? "" : lang) + item.Link + ">" + Res[item.Title] + "</a></dd>";
      });

      subMenuMarkup += "<li class='dropdown yamm-fw borderLeftY'><a href='#' title='' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>" + Res[item.Title] + "<b class='caret'></b></a>";
      subMenuMarkup += innerSubMenuMarkup + "</dl>";
      subMenuMarkup += "<dl class=''><dd class='picHolder'><img alt='' src='/PublishingImages/" + item.Image + "'/></dd></dl></div></div></li></ul></li>";
      cb(subMenuMarkup);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply from where you are getting that `id` it is undefined

Comment: I missed to update the id to mainItem.Id. Sorry about it. Try now.

Comment: Still there is issue item part is not resolved Res[item.Title] it gives error

Comment: Can we have Chat